# set nonProxyHosts in Apache HttpClient 4.1.3

Tags: proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I just cant help myself by answering this question.

How can I set nonProxyHosts in the Apache HttpClient 4.1.3?

In the old Httpclient 3.x that was quite simple. U could just set it using the setNonProxyHosts methods.

But now, there's no equivalent method for the new version. I have been looking trough the api docs, tutorials and examples and havent found the solution so far.

to set a normal proxy u can just do it by this:

```
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8080, "http");
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

Does anybody know if there is an out of the box solution in the new version httpclient 4.1.3 for setting up nonProxyHosts or do I have to do it on my own like

```
    if (targetHost.equals(nonProxyHost) {
    dont use a proxy
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i could solve this problem by using a proxyselector.

Comment: could you please commit your solution, i running into the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

@moohkooh: here is how i solved the problem.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

//use same proxy as set in the system properties by setting up a routeplan
ProxySelectorRoutePlanner routePlanner = new ProxySelectorRoutePlanner(client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry(),
    new LinkCheckerProxySelector());
client.setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);
```

And then your LinkcheckerProxySelector() would like something like that.

```
private class LinkCheckerProxySelector extends ProxySelector {

@Override
public List<Proxy> select(final URI uri) {

  List<Proxy> proxyList = new ArrayList<Proxy>();

  InetAddress addr = null;
  try {
    addr = InetAddress.getByName(uri.getHost());
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    throw new HostNotFoundWrappedException(e);
  }
  byte[] ipAddr = addr.getAddress();

  // Convert to dot representation
  String ipAddrStr = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < ipAddr.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      ipAddrStr += ".";
    }
    ipAddrStr += ipAddr[i] & 0xFF;
  }

//only select a proxy, if URI starts with 10.*
  if (!ipAddrStr.startsWith("10.")) {
    return ProxySelector.getDefault().select(uri);
  } else {
    proxyList.add(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
  }
  return proxyList;
}
```

So I hope this will help you.

Comment: since 4.0 `ProxySelectorRoutePlanner` is deprecated; doc tell to use `SystemDefaultRoutePlanner`instead. Anyway I will suggest a new way based onto environment

Answer (score 1):

Just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716909/how-do-i-replace-deprecated-httpclient-getparams-with-requestconfig). The quick way to do that is to set default system planner like ***oleg*** told :

```
HttpClientBuilder getClientBuilder() {
    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    SystemDefaultRoutePlanner routePlanner = new SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(null);
    clientBuilder.setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);
    return clientBuilder;
}
```

By default `null` arg will be set with `ProxySelector.getDefault()`

Anyway you could define and customize your own. Another example here : [EnvBasedProxyRoutePlanner.java (gist)](https://gist.github.com/boly38/31dfad5da388567e02e4)